# GitHub: Refresh failed: Could not connect to remote server

Tags: github, github-desktop

On GitHub Desktop (I use it on Windows), I have had this error over the last few days:

[image]

My Internet connection seems to work fine though. What could cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Is your internet connection goes through firewall/proxy server. I found that GitHub Windows client is only reliably works when no proxy enabled. Being windows (.NET to be precise) application it takes proxy settings as they defined in Internet Explorer connection settings. Meanwhile, Git itself, which GitHub Windows client desktop application simply uses via command prompt, is governed by http and https proxy settings in .gitconfig file or environment variables. This discrepancy makes it quite sophisticated to setup.

What's interesting, is that desktop app was working the first time I installed it fresh (never had it on this Windows), but it wasn't able to connect to GitHub. Then I started to fiddle with --global http/https settings and I broke the app. Now, even uninstalling and installing it back again, I still have connectivity issues, as it seems to remember settings somewhere, as it doesn't prompt me with welcome screen and does remember my name.

Worth to mention, that even if the app complains about connection, I can clone the repo with it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
In Internet Explorer:  Tools/Internet Options/Connections/LAN Settings
Uncheck "Use a Proxy server..."

Restart GitHub.
You might also be able to disable the Proxy Server via Edge.  In my case, I found that after turning it off in IE, it was off in Edge also.

Edit:  I also had to update the GitHub application in order to be able to clone to my local repository.